# R corrplot colors range

Tags: r, plot, r-corrplot

I am using corrplot in R to plot a correlation-coefficient matrix, but my correlations range only from 0.95 to 1.00, and I don't know how to set the lower and upper bounds of colors palette.

```
corrplot(segCorr, order = "hclust", tl.cex = .6, 
         cl.lim = c(0.95, 1), col=colorRampPalette(c("blue","white","red"))(10))
```

Despite of the settings everything is in one color, but I need to see these small differences in details.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28109647/r-corrplot-colorlegend-change-range seems to have a way... so try `d = mvtnorm::rmvnorm(50, c(0,0, 0), matrix(c(1, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1),3)) ; mypal = colorRampPalette(c("blue", "white", "red"))(10) ; color = rep(mypal, 100); 
corrplot(cor(d), order = "hclust", tl.cex = .6, cl.lim = c(0.85, 1),col=color)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A "hack" I sometimes use, to avoid spending too much time setting a good color-pallete, is to set `is.corr = FALSE`. Then we get from

```
with(mtcars, corrplot(cor(cbind(disp, hp, cyl)), cl.lim = c(0.7, 1)))
```

[image]

to...

```
with(mtcars, corrplot(cor(cbind(disp, hp, cyl)), cl.lim = c(0.7, 1), is.corr = FALSE))
```

[image]

Comment: Yup, great! Adding `is.corr = FALSE` to the parameters list of _corrplot_ resolved my issue. Many thanks!

Comment: For those trying to get this working, it seems cl.lim has been changed to col.lim on more recent versions of the corrplot package